# Automatically download document to user's desktop

Tags: php, html

There is a MS Word document sitting on a server exposed to the Internet. I have the complete path and parameters to locate the document and get it ready for download. I have looked for an html or php solution so that the word document is automatically downloaded and opened in Word on the user's desktop.

Answer (score 3):

You can prompt the user to download / start the download, but you can't force the user to download (automatically), or open it automatically. It's a question of security.

To download the application, just point the browser to the file. You can even use javascript and window.location if you don't want to do it with a link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can automatically download something and have it open. This would be a security issue.  The only way you would be able to do it is through something like an ActiveX control.  I've done a similar thing with printing automatically through an ActiveX control.  Of course this requires the user to install this when visiting the site for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

That is not going to happen.

You can not automatically download a Word Document and have it open on an end user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is point the browser to the file download when the page loads:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ktk5f/

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = 'https://web3.unt.edu/riskman/XLS/SELFINSP.XLS';
</script>
```

If it's a Word file, it will prompt the user to download the file to their computer. What happens at that point you would not have any control over. Note, some versions of Office will actually open a Word file within the IE window (like a PDF), so you may want to consider trying to open a new window for the download.